# Try/catch whole program

Tags: c++, exception, try-catch

I've taken the habit to construct my C++ projects as follows :

```
int main(int ac, char* av[])
{
    try
    {
       Object    foo;

       foo.run()
       /* ... */
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e)
    {
       std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
       return 1;
    }
    catch (...)
    {
       std::cerr << "Unknown error." << std::endl;
       return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I wonder if this is a good practice, or is it better to use try/catch blocks on small pieces of codes that are "expected" to produce errors ?

Comment: IMHO Exception handlers should be rare. They clutter up code, make it hard to read, hard to track errors, hard to maintain. Use them as little as possible. IMHO you should always handle errors directly when they occur if you possibly can. Exceptions should be left for the truly *exceptional* and not for simple errors.

Comment: @Galik: This is a last ditch diagnostic, nothing is really being handled here

Comment: @Galik If you want stack unwinding to work, you need exception throwing code to be in a try block at some level. Otherwise all bets are off.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put your whole program into such a top-level exception-handler, if you want to control how unhandled exceptions are handled (if they reach top-level).

There is a dis-advantage to that though: The standard crash-behavior is pre-empted, which probably means you get no crash-dumps, and thus are missing crucial information for post-mortem debugging.

Also, they might not reach top-level, but result in `std::unexpected()` and by that `std::terminate()` being called.

Thus, you might be better served by [`std::set_terminate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/set_terminate) even if you want to do your own thing.

Consider doing your own thing *and then crashing like normal* (Which you cannot do with your global exception-handler).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I can see how letting the program crash can help debugging (e.g using gdb backtrace), however, I fail to see the interest on managing it with std::set_terminate, if letting the program crash can help me debugging better, why should I bother handling errors at all ?

Comment: Ah, I advocate doing nothing of that kind, but *iff* you insist, `std::set_terminate` is a better starting-point than that top-level catch-block. (Of course, you should handle errors which are not programming-errors gracefully, which you probably already do.)

Answer (score 6):

Generally, catching all exceptions is not a good idea: you want to catch only these exceptions that your particular piece of code is ready to handle in a meaningful way.

However, the top-level entry point is an exception from this rule: it is a common practice to catch all exceptions yourself if you wish to control how exceptions are processed on the top level.

A common way of implementing it, however, is to write a single function that looks like `main`, but has a different name:

```
int entryPoint(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    ... // The real logic goes here
    Object    foo;

    foo.run()
    /* ... */
}
```

Your code looks like this, and never changes:

```
int main(int ac, char* av[])
{
    try
    {
        return entryPoint(ac, av);
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e)
    {
       std::cout << e.what() << std::cerr;
    }
    catch (...)
    {
       std::cout << "Unknown error." << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: you `entrypoint()` may still be called `main()`, but live in some named `namespace`.

Answer (score 2):

The advantage is your program never crashing (on Linux it can crash tough, since signals can't be caught as exceptions)

But there is one disadvantage I can think of: When you debug your code and have a run time error, you don't know where it was or see the stack. since your program continue running from the catch. so instead of check immediately what happened you need to run again and hope you'll have the same behavior.

Another thing: if your program is Multi-threaded, it won't help to caught all exceptions, since each thread need to catch his own exceptions.

Comment: Hope it never calls `std::unexpected()`.

Answer (score 1):

It's certainly better to try/catch as near the throw as possible if you can do something to recover from the error. Catching every fatal error on the other hand may clutter your code quite a bit.

If a throw is not caught, `std::terminate` will be called and you can set that function to a custom one with `std::set_terminate`. Inside the terminate function, you can do `throw;` which rethrows the uncaught object and then catch it. You must use `catch(...)` at the end in this case, since throwing from the terminate function is not a good thing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes surely it would make difference...Let's see how.

```
try
{
// code which could throw an exception
}
catch(Myexception& e)    //derived from std::exception
{
//do something.
}
//..some more code.                  //Point_1
```

Let's say I just want to do some manipulation after catching Myexception then then resume this function. After catching the exception code would come to POINT_1. Had I encapsulated this in try/catch it would have been ignored.